# Windows Server 2022 RDP connection fails with error 0x3 + extended error 0x11

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2022

### The Issue:

Today I started receiving an error while connecting to an Azure hosted Windows 2022 Server that until recently (2 or 3 days ago) were connecting fine.

The symptom: the connection error occurs after authentication (filled still in the client app) and passing all the security checks phases. When the RDP screen is to be rendered (it is created but still all black), it gives the error.

```
Your Remote Desktop Services session has ended, possibly for one of the following reasons:

The administrator has ended the session.
An error occurred while the connection was being established.
A network problem occurred.

For help solving the problem, see "Remote Desktop" in Help and Support.

[Expanded Information]
Error code: 0x3
Extended error code: 0x11
```

Note that this error happens even when connecting inside the server host to self (using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`).

### More Info:

The control to this server was handled to a technician who installed AnyDesk, and maybe it started some kind of conflict, but I'm not sure it is related.

Using Group Policy (`gpedit.msc`) all RDP settings related to Hardware Acceleration / RemoteFX optimizations / UDP connections were disabled, with no success.

Some (maybe) relevant Event Logs messages (I've translated them myself from pt-BR - ordered
from last to first):

```
Info    103     The disconnection reason is 17
Info    72      Method interface call: GetServerAutoReconnectInfo
Info    72      Method interface call: GetServerAutoReconnectInfo
Info    72      Method interface call: DisconnectNotify
Info    72      Method interface call: SetErrorInfo(0x11)
Info    72      Method interface call: PreDisconnect(17)
Info    132     The rdpdr channel was connected between server and client using transport tunnel: 0.
Info    132     The Microsoft::Windows::RDS::Geometry::v08.01 channel was connected between server and client using transport tunnel: 0.
Info    132     The Microsoft::Windows::RDS::Geometry::v08.01 channel was connected between server and client using transport tunnel: 0.
Info    132     The Microsoft::Windows::RDS::Video::Data::v08.01 channel was connected between server and client using transport tunnel: 0.
Info    132     The Microsoft::Windows::RDS::Video::Control::v08.01 channel was connected between server and client using transport tunnel: 0.
Info    72      Method interface call: ConnectNotify(SessionId=1)
Info    162     The client offers support to version 0xA0400 of RDP graphics protocol, client mode: 2, AVC available: 0. Initial Profile: 2. Server: MyServer
Info    132     The Microsoft::Windows::RDS::Graphics channel was connected between server and client using transport tunnel: 0.
Info    132     The Microsoft::Windows::RDS::Telemetry channel was connected between server and client using transport tunnel: 0.
Info    72      Method interface call: OnReady
Info    72      Method interface call: OnConnected
Info    169     The client operating system type is (1, 0). Server: MyServer
Info    132     The rdpinpt channel was connected between server and client using transport tunnel: 0.
Info    33      The RDP protocol will be using RemoteFX guest module to connect to the client computer.
Info    132     The rdpgrfx channel was connected between server and client using transport tunnel: 0.
Info    66      The RDP-Tcp#0 connection was assigned to session: 1
Info    72      Method interface call: AuthenticateClientToSession
Info    135     The multitransport connection was completed for tunnel: 3. The transport type was defined as TCP: Reason Code: 2 (Forced by Server Configuration).
Info    135     The multitransport connection was completed for tunnel: 1. The transport type was defined as TCP: Reason Code: 1 (No Client UDP Support).
Info    100     The server confirmed the client multi-transport feature.
Info    98      The TCP connection was successfully established.
Info    72      Method interface call: ProtocolComplete
Info    72      Method interface call: SendClientLicense
Info    72      Method interface call: GetSecurityFilterCreds
Info    71      The RDP-Tcp#0 connection uses video driver RDPUDD.
Info    104     The client timezone is [-3] UTC Time 
Info    72      Method interface call: AcceptConnection
Info    72      Method interface call: OnStartLicensing
```

Comment: I've been having this exact issue (Windows 11 though) and there seems to be nothing on the internet about it. Even looking up what the 0x11 extended code means leads to nothing, as the table I found listing all error codes doesn't include this specific one. Really frustrating.

Comment: It is very strange indeed - unfortunately, due to other situation, we ended rolling back to a Windows Server 2016. So we solved the issue not in an ideal way (not finding the root cause and going back to a version that soon will lead us to have upgrade the system again). Anyways - that's IT life....

Comment: I have the same issue, do you have any update? Can you resolve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: No, I didn't. Check my previous comment. I'm not aware of a solution, but I still hope someone might drop an answer.

Comment: Even right now my main machine (out of 3 in my local network) is doing this and I have no idea how to fix it. I tried everything I can other than wiping the system :( Have to resort to Chrome remote and nomachine as backup services.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue today with one of my Server 2022 nodes. In my case I found it was because I disabled the Microsoft Remote Display Adapter while trying to clear my cluster validation report to zero warnings. Once the adapter is disabled it doesn't seem to be able to be re-enabled via the gui. (I have an OOB management connection so I can still get to the gui)

I un-installed the device entirely and established a new RDP session and the driver is back and I can remote in.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I was getting almost the exact same issue. It started 2-3 days after I deployed the VM. One difference is that I was getting 0x10, not 0x11 like yours.

I was still able to use PSREMOTING into the server. So I disabled Sophos AV from the cli and it started working again. I'm going to re-install Sophos Endpoint, and try to open a ticket with them to see if they can figure it out. The endpoint logs showed no entries, but it is Sophos, so who knows.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, looking at the Event Log i can see it was the video driver! Microsoft installed automatically "Intel(R) Q35 Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.0)" driver which caused a conflict with Microsoft Remote Display Adapter. What I had to do was revert to the previous controller in the the Display Settings in Devices Manager, and it reverted to Microsoft Basic Display Adapter. Problem solved!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wow Thanks Ryan Swinney for the hint about the display adapter.

In my case I never disabled it, but I do update/change my Nvidia driver often for testing and maybe this led the RDP adapter to stay in a buggy state.

The solution that worked for me is this:

- Open device manager. Select View->Show hidden devices.
- Open Display adapters category and Right-click "Microsoft Remote Display Adapter" then "Uninstall".

This of course requires that you have access to the remote PC either physically or through some other service like Chrome remote.

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution for our problem, in our case the problem was the Antivirus (McAfee), we had a policy that blocked access to computers with Windows Server 2022.

Thank you all for the help, I hope my input can help you solve your cases.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the problem on this site:
https://chowdera.com/2022/154/202206032340171247.html

On a new harddisk on windows server "localhost\users" (on a domaincontroller domain\users) has read access. If you remove the read access for "users" on the systemdrive (C:) you can't access the server via RDP.

I don't understand the dependency, but it works on two servers when I restore the read access for "users" on the systemdrive.

Greetings from Germany
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well.  I caused the problem myself by removing the local users group (SERVERNAME\Users) from access to the c drive in the security permissions section. of the Remote Desktop server.  Once I put that back in place the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it's been reason 0x3 and extended 0xf (15). The cause was:
**Group Policy (gpedit.msc) > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Device Installation > Restrictions > Block installation of interchangeable devices**
being activated. I set this back to default (not configured) and it's working again. Windows 11.

I translated this from a German system, so please forgive me if the names of the GP Edit path are not 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same problem when I tried to use RDP in the Safe Mode and Active Directory recovery Mode.

I was checking this hints:
https://chowdera.com/2022/154/202206032340171247.html
and it was about the RDP display drivers etc.

It was resolved after I installed the 2022-12 KB5021249 21H2

https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5021249

And there is a list of files replaced by this update and includes the RDP stuff:

https://download.microsoft.com/download/b/1/3/b1383434-8331-4a7e-a029-cc9397fd9964/5021249.csv

It's gone for me. I've spent a lot of time checking what couldbe wrong but it just got solved after installing this updates.

Thanks for all of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact same error and symptom with a client today.

Although the varied answers here shows it's a fairly generic error, the issue in our case was connecting from a PC with a HighDPI Screen (2K Resolution) to a PC with an older Graphics Chipset (Intel G33);

I'm not sure if it's that chipset's maximum resolution or the fact it only had a WDDM 1.0 driver running it was the root cause, but putting the client PC down to HD Resolution (1080p) let it connect without issue, proving that was the problem. Client PC is getting replaced with something better, now.

Answer (score 0):

I use wmic to execute remote commands, and call pnputil to remove "Microsoft Remote Display Adapter". Then I can connect RDP successfully.

```
wmic /node:IP /user:USER /password:PASSWORD process call create "pnputil /remove-device /deviceid RdpIdd_IndirectDisplay"
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my users ran into this issue.

He is using the Microsoft Remote Desktop Client app from a Dell Wyse thin client. Another user had used the computer before so the virtual desktop subscription wasn't using the same account (email address).

We solved the issue by unsubscribing from this account and subscribing again with the correct user account.

Have a nice day ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error after unknowingly installing a Carbon Black (CB) agent that was too old for Server 2022. (Sensor Version 3.6.0.1979.)

This thread helped me home in on CB being the culprit after seeing others having issues with their AV agents.

The error we were getting was Windows Server 2022 RDP connection fails with error 0x3 + extended error 0x10, rather than 0x11.

Putting CB into bypass restored RDP access. We are now in the process of updating the CB agent.

According to [CB doco](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Carbon-Black-Cloud/services/cbc-oer-win-sensor-on-server/GUID-149AAA9E-05D0-4208-B210-B1EF04C9C8B6.html), Agent Version 3.7-3.9 is required for Server 2022.

Answer (score 0):

I often have this or similar RDC errors after installing OS updates. The reason is that not all services which startup mode are "Automatic" or "Automatic (Delayed Start)" are started, without any clues in EventLog.

My guess is that process of installing updates breaks startup timing and some longer starting services just silently give up to start because of timeout caused by updates.

Resolution is to manually start all these services (sometimes one, sometimes more). Simple reboot also helps but not always possible for server for production reasons.